Error when defining types for Context object
The below code is showing error
*"Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1"*
type TodosContextObj = {
  items: Todo[];
  addTodo: (text: string) => void;
  removeTodo: (id: string) => void;
};
 
export const TodosContext = createContext<TodosContextObj>({
  items: [],
  addTodo: (text: string) => {},
  removeTodo: (id: string) => {},
});

Here's full file (todos-context.tsx)
import { createContext } from "vm";
import { useState } from "react";
import { FC } from "react";
import Todo from "../models/todo";
 
type TodosContextObj = {
  items: Todo[];
  addTodo: (text: string) => void;
  removeTodo: (id: string) => void;
};
 
export const TodosContext = createContext<TodosContextObj>({
  items: [],
  addTodo: (text: string) => {},
  removeTodo: (id: string) => {},
});
 
const TodosContextProvider: FC<{ children?: React.ReactNode }> = (props) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([]);
 
  const addTodoHandler = (enteredText: string) => {
    const newTodo = new Todo(enteredText);
 
    setTodos((prevTodos) => prevTodos.concat(newTodo));
  };
 
  const removeTodoHandler = (todoId: string) => {
    console.log(todoId);
 
    setTodos((prevTodos) => prevTodos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== todoId));
  };
 
  console.log(todos);
 
  const contextValue: TodosContextObj = {
    items: todos,
    addTodo: addTodoHandler,
    removeTodo: removeTodoHandler,
  };
 
  return (
    <TodosContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </TodosContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default TodosContextProvider;

Here i just want to set types for object (i.e. context) passed in createContext 
The types for createContext & contextValue are same

It should be import { createContext } from "react";, not import { createContext } from "vm";. Your editor's auto-import probably accidentally grabbed the wrong createContext.

You are importing createContext from the wrong node_module.
It should be this way
import { createContext } from "react";
instead of
import { createContext } from "vm";
The createContext you need for the context API is exported in react.
